# r extension netlogo, object 'economicvalue' not found

Tags: r, netlogo, r-extension

I am working in netlogo on a model which has to communicate with R during the run. I do this using the r extension in netlogo (so not Rnetlogo in R).

at the setup I load my script with 
`r:eval "source('C:/Users/keemi/OneDrive/Documenten/Thesis/heatpumps/scriptHeatpumpV1.R')"`
this works fine since I can ask what I want coming from the script with this code. `r:get "cpquery(fittedHeatpumpv1, event = (Reliability == 0.88), evidence = (Economic == 0.08))"` this gives me a chance percentage of the event given the evidence.

However the evidence must come from the netlogo network, I do this using
`r:put "economicvalue" reliability` this creates a variable in r -> economicvalue from the value of reliability in netlogo (which is 0.08 for the example).
I then put in the following code `r:get "cpquery(fittedHeatpumpv1, event = (Reliability == 0.88), evidence = (Economic == economicvalue))"` to get to the same result, however netlogo gives the error

`Extension exception: Error in R-Extension: Error in Get. 
org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in eval(evidence, generated.data, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'economicvalue' not found`

`error while company 157 running R:GET
  called by procedure INVEST
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go-once'`

this is odd since if I do the same thing in r itself it works just fine. and the script itself also works fine since I can load things from it. 
I also checked the value of the r:put and this was indeed set to 0.08 if I call it back using `r:get "economicvalue"`

I also tested it already without the variable coming from netlogo but just giving the command directly to r using `r:eval "economicvalue <- 0.08"`but the same error occurs.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here, since the code works in r itself if I put the same code lines but not coming from netlogo, and netlogo also performs well since I can see if the r commands work with the `r:get` and this all gives the right values.

could somebody help me out?